# How to extract data from this table and convert it into this specific format using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. Below is the extract from a table called `Table1`:

```
ID     Market    Adult   AdultAge   0-5   6-12   13-17
100     UK         1        50       0     0       0
105     UK         2        36       0     0       0
107     DE         1        65       0     1       0
110     FR         2        42       0     2       1 
115     BE         1        18       1     0       0
```

Columns 0-5, 6-12 and 13-17 are age categories and contain the count of children.

I need to convert this Table into the following format and using the following logic:

- If count of Adult is 2, then the 2nd Adult's age will be the recorded age minus 2.
- Child's age will be the mid-point of its age category. That is, if there 1 child (or 2 or more children) in a particular category (say, 6-12), then the age of the child (or each child if more than 1), will be (12+6)/2 = 9 years. Same logic applies to the other age categories.

So, here is the final output I am looking for:

```
ID      Market   Age    Category
100     UK       50      Adult
105     UK       36      Adult
105     UK       34      Adult
107     DE       65      Adult
107     DE        9      Child
110     FR       42      Adult
110     FR       40      Adult
110     FR        9      Child
110     FR        9      Child
110     FR       15      Child
115     BE       18      Adult
115     BE        2.5    Child
```

I am thinking of using some `CASE` statements to convert the data but I am really confused as to how to implement same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can the columns Adult,0-5,6-12,13-17 have a value higher than 2?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Column Adult will not exceed 2 but columns 0-5, 6-12 and 13-17 may exceed 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complicated, but a numbers table would help.  You can easily generate one using a recursive CTE (up to 100), or you might have one lying around.

Then you need to unpivot and apply a bit more logic:

```
with numbers as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from numbers
      where n <= 10
     )
select x.*
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select t1.ID, t1.Market, category,
             (case when v.category = 'Adult' and n.n = 2 then v.age - 2
                   else v.age
              end) as age
      from (values (t1.AdultAge, 'Adult', t1.Adult),
                   (2.5, 'Child', t1.[0-5]),
                   (9, 'Child', t1.[6-12]),
                   (15, 'Child', t1.[13-17])
           ) v(age, category, cnt) join
           numbers n
           on n.n <= v.cnt
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8f998f77188e14d56854e595f962c8e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You need an elaborate `unpivot`. One way to do this is to use a tally table to create multiple rows, and also use `cross apply`:

```
;WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT t.id,t.market,q.*
FROM  [Table1] t
outer apply
(
    select t.adultage,'Adult' where adult>=1
    union all
    select adultage-2,'Adult' where adult=2
    union all
    select 2.5,'Child' from Tally where n<=[0-5]
    union all
    select 9,'Child' from Tally  where n<=[6-12]
    union all
    select 15,'Child' from Tally  where n<=[13-17]
)q(Age,Category)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. May I ask what the "1000 rows" commented in your codes mean?

Comment: The CTE (`WITH..`) t creates a table named `Tally`, with a column named `n`,which has 1000 rows, with n values from 1 to 1000. My query won't work for values over 1000 in columns [0-5] etc.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it won't work if the number of rows in Table1 (that is, my table) is over 1000?

Comment: No, it will work for any amount of rows. It won't work if, for example, the value of the [0-5] column in one row is more than 1000. I guess you won't have such numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now!

Comment: Hi George, I have encountered some cases where the Adult Count have exceeded 2. What modification would I need to bring to your solution for it work ?

Comment: Adult Count can have a max value of 3.

Comment: ...and what age would the third adult have?

Comment: 3rd adult will also be Age - 2